# Is it possible to delete a file from GitHub and also erase all evidence of its existence

Tags: github

Is it possible to delete a file from github.com and also erase all evidence that it ever existed?

When I click on history, I can see all modifications of the github project, including deletion of files and directories. Is it possible to put a data file, then delete it, and then delete the evidence of its existence from history?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

However, since git is a versioning tool and was not actually made to change the history and permanently remove files, it can be implemented.

But be aware, the selected file will be removed from the Git history, and you can no longer access a previous version of that file, it will be removed from the `.git` folder until it is tracked again at some point.

With `git-filter-repo` you can rewrite your Git history and remove a file from every commit that it was involved with. Read the [documentation](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) about it.

Another alternative is the [*BFG Repo-Cleaner*](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).